Questions in the proof of Mackey's formula by module theory
I'm reading Zimmermann's Representation Theory:
A Homological Algebra Point of View these days. To prove Mackey's formula, the author proved a lemma below, which I can still understand:
$$RG\simeq\bigoplus_{KgH\in K\backslash G/H}RK\otimes_{K\cap gHg^{-1}}gRH$$
Then he proved Mackey's formula by
$$
\begin{aligned}
M\uparrow_{H}^{G}\downarrow_{K}^{G}&\simeq\left(\bigoplus_{KgH\in K\backslash G/H}RK\otimes_{K\cap gHg^{-1}}gRH\right)\otimes M\\
&\simeq\bigoplus_{KgH\in K\backslash G/H}RK\otimes_{K\cap gHg^{-1}}gRH\otimes M\\
&\simeq\bigoplus_{KgH\in K\backslash G/H}RK\otimes_{K\cap gHg^{-1}}gM\\
&\simeq\bigoplus_{KgH\in K\backslash G/H}\left[{^g(M\downarrow_{H\cap gKg^{-1}}^{H})}\right]\uparrow_{gHg^{-1}\cap K}^{K}
\end{aligned}
$$
I believe he used an isomorphism ${^g(M\downarrow_{H\cap gKg^{-1}}^{H})}\simeq gM\downarrow^{G}_{K\cap gHg^{-1}}$ to get the last equation, but I can't prove it. Moreover, this isomorphism makes no sense many ways, like $^g(M\downarrow_{H\cap gKg^{-1}}^{H})$ may possibly not be a $R(gHg^{-1}\cap K)$ module.
In fact, I noticed that the Mackey's formula in other textbook (Like Representation and Cohomology) differs from Zimmermann's. Maybe the book just gave a wrong theorem and proof.
I've been struggling whole night and I'd be appreciate if anyone can help.

It's notoriously annoying to make sure that all of the cosets and conjugation elements are in the right place in Mackey's formula. It could be you need a $g^{-1}$ rather than a $g$. Certainly tensoring $gM$ over $K\cap gHg^{-1}$ means you need to end up with a $K\cap gHg^{-1}$-module. So if you start off with $H$, you need to restrict down to $H\cap g^{-1}Kg$, then left-conjugate by $g$ to get a $gHg^{-1}\cap K$-module.

@DavidA.Craven I tried this before but mislead by assuming Zimmermann's formula is correct. Now I found the revised version match with the other materials' formula. Thank you : )
